# Module Apache mod_remoteip cause SSL Handshake failed (5) when load testing

Tags: apache, ssl, haproxy, proxy-protocol

I have Haproxy which load balance the traffic to two apache servers.
When I benchmark with [apache benchmark tool](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html) I have no errors and everything works as expected.

**But when I activate the proxy protocol** communication between HAProxy and apaches I start having issues.

There are two scenarios

1- Load testing with less then 500 request/second everything works well.

2- Load testing with **concurrent requests > 600**.  I start having **SSL handshake failed (5)** issues.

- Here is my HAproxy configuration:

  ```
   #---------------------------------------------------------------------
   # Global settings
   #---------------------------------------------------------------------
   global
   log 127.0.0.1 local0 debug
   chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
   pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
   maxconn     3000
   user        haproxy
   group       haproxy
   daemon

   # turn on stats unix socket
   stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats

   #---------------------------------------------------------------------
   # common defaults that all the 'listen' and 'backend' sections will
   # use if not designated in their block
   #---------------------------------------------------------------------
   defaults
   mode                    tcp
       log                     global
       option                  tcplog
       option                  dontlognull
       option http-server-close
       option                  redispatch
       retries                 3
       timeout http-request    10s
       timeout queue           1m
       timeout connect         10s
       timeout client          1m
       timeout server          1m
       timeout http-keep-alive 10s
       timeout check           10s
   #---------------------------------------------------------------------
   # Servers sections
   #---------------------------------------------------------------------
   frontend XXXX:443
     bind XXX:443
     mode tcp
     use_backend https_front

   backend https_front
     balance roundrobin
     server XXX XXX check send-proxy
  ```
- My apache vhost conf:

  ```
  <VirtualHost *:443>
    ...
    ServerName XXXX
    RemoteIPProxyProtocol On
  ```
- My benchmark command:

  ```
   > ab  -c 1020 -n 9000  https://XXXX
    ...
   SSL handshake failed (5).
   SSL handshake failed (5).
   SSL handshake failed (5).
   SSL handshake failed (5).
   SSL read failed (1) - closing connection
   139921183344512:error:140E0197:SSL routines:SSL_shutdown:shutdown while in init:ssl/ssl_lib.c:2094:
  ...
  ```

I can not find any logs neither in haproxy nor in the apache logs. Did someone face the same issue before ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would try asking on ServerFault.  Since this is not a programming question.

Comment: What is the hardware configurations/connections (network layout, both physical and logical, Don't need specific IP's, any routers L3 switches in the mix?)  Is there a virtual environment / servers involved?

Comment: first thanks for your response @strom, I do not have a clear view in the hardware configuration but  I am running my server in a VM, both the HAproxy and apache are in the same network, if I benchmark directly the apache I can go over 5k request/second, but when the Haproxy are added to the stack I can just reach 600 request/second before having problems